# Activiti, how to add listener for timer endding?

Tags: workflow, activiti

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE6OM.png)

Hello, I have encounterred a problem about adding a listener to the end event of a timer. I used an  intermediate catch event timer to wait a certain period(5 min). After 5 min, the flow goes to task2.
I want to update data in another table(some code in java), so I need a listener that listens the end event of the timer. However, the methods that I tried failed. Would you mind showing me a feasible and easily acomplishable way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: You can either use the Task Listener as suggested by Greg or you can add a service task after the timer and insert data in that service task.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add a Task Listener to the complete event of your timer step?
https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/delegate/tasklistener